# Broken Archimesh file

Tags: archimesh-add-on

I was working on a model of a building with a lot of windows and doors.

Everything was working fine until I could not edit the properties of the windows. I get "Warning: Operator does not work in local view mode".

I suspected one archimesh object was inserted inside another mesh, so I tried deleting all archimesh objects of the model.

The error persisted.

What else can I try to fix the file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Local View Mode" is kind of a fake, selected-objects collection which you can enter which toggles all non-selected objects visibility automatically and the camera zooms-in on the selected-objects.

To get out of that view, click the <kbd>/</kbd> key. Or follow the UI steps shown in the screenshot below.

[image]